# Installing Xubuntu 14.04 desktop over ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, laptop

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on a friends laptop. He wanted the Xubuntu 14.04 desktop on it because the graphics card is not able to fully handle the graphics of 16.04.

Does anyone know what terminal commands I should use to install the desktop for XUbuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to instal Xubuntu 14.04 over an ubuntu distribution is:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

If you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, you can remove them via `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-restricted-extras` and then install the ones for xubuntu via `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Finally, run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` for a final cleanup.

Comment: Wouldn't that command install xubuntu 16.04 desktop over the ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Comment: Nope. `apt-get install` uses packages suitable for the installed Ubuntu version. You'll get the 14.04 version of Xubuntu this way.

Comment: Exactly. Ubuntu updating always remains within your version, unless you explicitly add the option of another version. There is also the command to upgrade the full distribution to the newest stable version (16.04), by running `sudo  apt dist-upgrade`. But that is another story. (BTW, if the answer was helpful, you could mark it as solved.  This might help other users finding useful answers.)